# Entity Framework can't see computed columns of the View

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, view, calculated-columns

Does EF support computed columns in SQLite views?

I just added a view to my SQLite database. While EF can see the view and does create an entity for it when I issue "Update Model from Database..." command, the generated entity does not have any property corresponding to the computed column of my view (which btw was the whole reason for which I created the view).

Is the known/documented problem, or am I doing something wrong?

This is my View:

```
SELECT [Id], 
   [ProjectId], 
   [Start], 
   [End], 
   [Deleted], 
   [LastUpdate], 
   (JULIANDAY ([End]) - JULIANDAY ([Start])) * 86400000 AS [Duration]
FROM   [Timeslot]
```

It cannot see the `Duration` column for some reason.

### Edit

Thinking about CL's answer, I tried to explicitly cast the problematic column to `INTEGER`, to help SQLite recognize its type:

```
CAST (((JULIANDAY ([End]) - JULIANDAY ([Start])) * 86400000) AS [INTEGER]) AS [Duration]
```

Doesn't prove any good.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [problem](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview?name=46166bd492) with EF that can be worked around by specifying a default data type for such columns in the connection string, or as an environment variable in `System.Data.SQLite.dll.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DefaultFlags_SQLiteConnection" value="DetectTextAffinity, DetectStringType" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I added it to `System.Data.SQLite.dll.config` and restarted VS. EF still doesn't bring in the problematic column.

Comment: I also tried to explicitly cast my computed column to the actual type (see edit), to help SQLite recognize it. No gain.